# Android FirebaseAuth Creating results in cannot find symbol class NonNull

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im building a native app in android studio and I am using the following Auth.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
```

I am getting an error when building/running that

```
cannot find symbol class NonNull
```

This is happening with this code.

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }
            }
        });
```

I searched before I came here and I do have these set in my gradle.properties file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Where is that error coming from?

Comment: the oncomplete method... i posted all code above.

Comment: There are multiple lines inside onComplete. Which one produces that error?

Comment: Alex...? cannot find symbol class NonNull... it tells you, its the annotation.

Comment: Have you tried to add the correct import for `NonNull`?